# How to integrate grails 2 with angular 4 or 5?

Tags: angular, grails

I have a Grails 2.3.9 project using completely the GSP nechanims defined by the Grails Framework.

Now, I need to convert this to a Grails (REST) + Angular (4 or 5) project. Also I need all the resources to be in the same project, not in two separated projects running independently, the main problem here is that I don't find anywhere a way to integrate Angular 5 with Grails 2, all I see on the web and forums is Grails 2 + AngularJS or the new Grails 3 Angular profile, but i can't use those options.

To resume, how can i integrate Angular (4 or 5) with Grails 2, not two separated projects running independently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "To resume, is there a way to integrate Angular (4 or 5) with Grails 2, not two separated projects running independently?" - Yes, of course.  As far as Grails is concerned, the Angular stuff is just a bunch of static resources that need to be served up.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thank you very much for your answer, maybe my question should be "how", angular is a bunch of static resources, but in this case i have angular that use typescript that needs to be compiled first, so, i think is not that simple like add in a .gsp a .js file

Comment: That is indeed a separate question.  You might be interested in looking at the Grails 2 typescript plugin.

Comment: @Daniel could you solved your issue?